# How do I minimize round-trips to SQL with user-based authorization?

Tags: sql, postgresql, model-view-controller, authorization, role-base-authorization

Context: MVC web service backed by a SQL DB. Say I have a user relation in my database, and a set of relations that reference it through a chain of FKs. So for example let's say I have the table:

```
sales_people
car_dealership
cars
```

where a sales person belongs to a certain car dealership, and so do cars. Sales people should only be able to see cars that belong to their specific dealership. I have a few options here:

**I can bake the authorization business logic into the SQL query itself:**

```
SELECT *
FROM cars as c, sales_people AS sp, car_dealerships AS cd
WHERE where c.dealership_id = cd.id
AND sp.dealership_id = cd.id
AND sp.id = ?
AND c.id = ?
```

assuming the caller has verified that the sales_people id is legit and prevents trivial spoofing of that id, then the query above would prevent a user from getting hold of cars that aren't his. This could probably be extended to an arbitrary # of tables as long as the join isn't too massive.

Upside? One single DB call.

Downside?

- the authorization business logic here is very basic. User referenced by one of those tables? Sure, you can pass. However let's say I have to have more complex access rules. It's likely they might simply not be doable with one simple query.
- It's hard to tell if the user requested an unauthorized row OR if the row is authorized but doesn't actually exist, so that makes error reporting tricky. You wouldn't know if you should report a 200 or a 403 (although depending on the type of API you might want to always use 200 in these cases to prevent exposing too much information to an attacker).

The other option I see is to **make extra queries before or after the fact** to validate the data is indeed accessible to that user. E.g. get list of ids of cars the sales person is authorized to get and THEN perform the query on that subset, or the exact other way around.

The upside is obviously that I can make more calls and run more logic in the business layer and be as sophisticated as I want.

The downside is that I will be generating more DB traffic which could be a deal-breaker depending on how frequent that request is made.

**I'm probably missing a few other options here, and I'd love to hear how you've solved the problem before. Is there a better way?**

Comment: What is the *latency* between the MVC (webservice? other?) and the DB? That is, is the issue with HTTP<->SVC or SVC<->DB? If it's HTTP<->SVC, I would recommend focusing on domain-specific queries and responses that utilize a hierarchical model. If the SVC<->DB link is good then how this is generated may become "less important".

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept of hierarchical model responses. Could you clarify?

Comment: Regarding the other point, at this point I'm not worrying about HTTP<->SVC portion because I'm condensing most of the work at the web service level, so the round-trips from browser to api are already at a minimum.

Answer (score 4):

I think as a general rule, you should make the code behave logically, and then scale the performance in other ways, e.g. bigger more powerful database or caching results.

For my application, I use multiple queries. I've timed our system, and 5-10 round trips take less than 1 ms. That's good enough for me. I've seen others create complicated stored procedures to do everything they want. The result is that they can return things like 403 or 404 from the database.

I personally would prefer to make multiple trips to the database to make the code cleaner and easier to read. This is especially true if your load is not too big. Hardware is cheap, but your time is not.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another opinion after debugging a few more of these issues.

It's nice to tell the user (or application code) what exactly is wrong. My usual approach now is to return from SQL all the relevant security information and then do the check in the application. This way, there's one round trip to the database, and you can give very detailed information from the code, e.g. "You are no longer have access to this dealership." or "This car has been deleted.".